# Is $\mathbb Q-\mathbb N$ dense in $\mathbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Is $\mathbb Q-\mathbb N$ dense in $\mathbb R$? I believe that the solution is about two relatively prime integers. However, I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Joe Actually, it's `\mathbb Q`.

Comment: @Joe I tried that but simulation below the question box just showed me exactly as Q. Therefore I was not sure to use it.

Comment: @CyclotomicField for any interval (x,y), take 2 integers a and b which are relatively prime so that they do not form a integer. Then multiply both sides with b gives us bx < a < by.

Comment: @amdryzen7000: What definition of "dense" are you using?

Comment: For a subset of a set, for every interval (a,b) (Here a and b are in the set) there exists a 'p' in subset that is a < p < b.

Comment: @amdryzen7000: Okay. Here is a sketch of a proof: since $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$, we know that given any interval $(a,b)$ there is a $q\in\mathbb Q$ such that $a<q<b$. We consider two cases: if $q\not\in\mathbb N$ then we have exhibited a $q\in\mathbb Q-\mathbb N$ such that $a<q<b$; if $q\in\mathbb N$ then let $n$ be a positive integer that is large enough for us to have $q+\frac{1}{10^n}<b$. (You can prove that there always exists such an $n$ by contradiction.) Then $q+\frac{1}{10^n}$ is rational, not an integer, and lies in the interval $(a,b)$.

Comment: One way: Show that each nonempty bounded open interval contains infinitely many rational points and only finitely many integers. From this it immediately follows that each nonempty bounded open interval contains at least one (in fact, infinitely many) points in ${\mathbb Q} - \mathbb N.$

Comment: @Joe Alright, in the case where q is an natural number; I proved that the fraction you add to q have a limit point at 0. Actually, I first assumed it is 0 at limit. Then I proved it with epsilon. I believe it is sufficient.

Comment: @amdryzen7000: I'm not sure I follow. You need to choose an $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $\frac{1}{10^n}<b-q$. So try proving, by contradiction, that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is an $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $\frac{1}{10^n}<\varepsilon$. (To prove it formally, you should use the least upper bound property of $\mathbb R$.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's try to find a noninteger rational between any two reals. For any real numbers $a <b$, since $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$, there is $p\in(a,b)\cap \mathbb Q$. If $p\notin \mathbb N$, it is our desired rational. Otherwise, there is $q\in(p,b)\cap\mathbb Q$. If $q\notin \mathbb N$, it is our desired rational. Otherwise, since $p < q$ and $p,q\in\mathbb N$, we have $p < p + 1/2 < q$ and $p + 1/2 \notin \mathbb N$. Since $a < p < p + 1/2 < q < b$,  $p + 1/2$ is our desired rational.

Comment: What a cool proof! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a topological perspective:

If $X,Y \subset Z$ and $X$ is discrete in $Z$ while $Y$ is dense in $Z$, then $Y-X$ is dense in $Z$.

Indeed, assume the contrary, i.e. $Y-X$ is not dense. Then there exists $a \in Z$ and a neighborhood $U$ of $a$ such that $U \cap (Y-X) = \emptyset$. Since $X$ is discrete, you can shrink $U$ so that $U \cap X = \emptyset$. But then $U \cap Y = \emptyset$, being the union of two empty sets. This would imply that $Y$ is not dense, contradiction.

EDIT: this answer is incorrect, the shrinking argument is false.

Comment: Thanks for you kind help, however I know nothing about topology. Anyway, one will benefit from that comment!

Comment: Your argument is wrong. There are such things called discrete topological spaces. Then $X$ is dense and discrete but $X \setminus X = \emptyset$ is not dense!

Comment: @JonathanSchilhan “$X$ is discrete in $Z$” means that every point of $X$ is isolated.

Comment: @egreg Yes that's the definition I am using. Imagine a space with a single point. That point is isolated, but if you remove it you end up with nothing.

Comment: @JonathanSchilhan Add “proper subset”.

Comment: @egreg I don't know what you are trying to say. $\{ 1\}$ is also discrete in $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N} \setminus \{1\}$ is not dense in $\mathbb{N}$. The statement is simply false in general.

Comment: I see your point @JonathanSchilhan, it seems you are correct. I still think there should be a topological statement that generalizes the original question, but I am not sure what it is.

Comment: I guess this is equivalent to the question 'if $X \subset Y$, under what conditions is $Y-X$ dense in $Y$?'

Comment: @ThomasBakx Yes, the argument in the answer works when $Z$ does not have isolated points and is $T_1$. Without these assumptions there are lots of counterexamples.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have proven that $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$, we know that if $x<y$ then there is a $q\in\mathbb Q$ such that $x<q<y$. However, we can actually establish a stronger result: if $x<y$ then there are infinitely many $q\in\mathbb Q$ such that $x<q<y$. To prove this, suppose for the sake of contradiction that there are only finitely many rational numbers lying strictly between $x$ and $y$. This means that there is a *least* rational $q_0$ such that $x<q_0<y$. Therefore, there is no rational number $q$ such that $x<q<q_0$, contradicting the density of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$.

Can you see how this implies that $\mathbb Q-\mathbb N$ is dense in $\mathbb R$? Hint: between any two real numbers, there are only finitely many natural numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Let $r\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\varepsilon>0$. Then

1. $(r-\varepsilon,r+\varepsilon)\cap\mathbb{Q}$ is infinite, because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$;
2. $(r-\varepsilon,r+\varepsilon)\cap\mathbb{N}$ is finite.

Therefore
$$
(r-\varepsilon,r+\varepsilon)\cap(\mathbb{Q}-\mathbb{N})=
\bigl((r-\varepsilon,r+\varepsilon)\cap\mathbb{Q}\bigr)-
\bigl((r-\varepsilon,r+\varepsilon)\cap\mathbb{N}\bigr)
$$
is infinite, in particular not empty.

We use that $A\cap(B-C)=(A\cap B)-(A\cap C)$.

Answer (score 0):

You can see that $\mathbb{Q}-\mathbb{N}$ is dense in $\mathbb{Q}$.(If $q\in \mathbb{N}$, consider $q_n=q+1/(n+1)$.
$\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ and hence...